# How do I publish a Solution (.sln File) using Process in C#

Tags: c#, process, publish

I am trying to publish a .NET Core 3.1 Solution using the code below. It works fine with the variables given here.
(It is a Console Application that is being debugged and a WinForm that is running this code).

```
string batchFilePath = @"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat";

string solutionFilePath = @"D:\Documents\Visual Studio\Visual Studio 2022\Projects\Selfmade\Selfmade.sln";
```

I run the following code and it will debug the solution in the default debug folder.

```
                    Process process = new Process();

                    var command = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ComSpec");
                    command = @"" + command + @"";
                    var args = string.Format($"/S/K \" \"{batchFilePath}\" && devenv /build Debug \"{solutionFilePath}\" && exit \"");


                    process.StartInfo.FileName = command;
                    process.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
                    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

                    process.Start();
```

However this code debugs the solution. I am looking for a simulair way but then to publish this solution. The only issue is that I tried using the `dotnet.exe` but I cannot seem to figure out any way to publish this solution using a process.

My question is, Is there a way to use a code simulair to this but then for publishing the solution and how do you do it?

Comment: When you say "publish", what exactly is the end result you are seeking to achieve?

Comment: @zenilogix I want to punlish a solutuon using visual studio, by code. Like shown in the code up here